# How do I use select_year with form_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, simple-form, form-for

I have a form as follows:

```
<%= form_for(@car, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
  <% if @car.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@car.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this car from being saved</h2>
      <ul>
        <% @car.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :price %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :price %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :model_year %><br />
    <%  %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I want to have a collection select for the model year starting  100 years back and going to a year in the future.  I have tried

```
<%= f.select_year :model_year%>
```

but it says that select_year is not a valid method.  Tried

```
<%= f.date :model_year, :discard_month => true %>
```

also to no avail.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`select_year` is a helper that generates a full select tag with options. Since you're using `form_for` instead of `form_tag`, you'll want to use a helper that can be called on a form builder object.

```
<%= f.select :model_year, (Time.zone.now.year - 100)..(Time.zone.now.year + 1) %>
```

Reference: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-select_year

Comment: undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #20):

17: 
18:   <div class="field">
19:     <%= f.label :model_year %><br />
20:     <%= f.select :model_year, (@car.model_year - 100)..(@car.model_year + 1)  %>
21:   </div>
22: 
23:   <div class="field">

Comment: my model_year attribute is a date.  t.date     "model_year" not sure what that error could mean

Comment: It means your `model_year` is `nil`, or possibly the whole object is `nil`. When you're creating a new object, we're going to need something different.

Comment: Actually I misunderstood your question. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, the only other thing I had to do to get the attribute to save was change my model_year column to an integer from a date.  Thanks!!

Comment: Since it generally makes more sense to have year selection in chronologic descending order, this may come in handy for someone: `(Time.now.year).downto(Time.now.year - 100).to_a`.

Comment: This is called perfect answer